# datetime conversion getting Error while Convert using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

```
string FromDate;
string objFromDate="04/18/2017";

FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(objFromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", 
           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here i Convert dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy but am getting string was not recognized as a valid datetime. Can any one please help me how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Does "04/18/2017" look like a date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format to you?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're passing `04/18/2017` when the expected format is `dd/MM/yyyy` and there obviously isn't month with number 18. Try setting `objFromDate = "18/04/2017"` and see if it helps.

Comment: i try to convert objFromDate="04/18/2017" to objFromDate = "18/04/2017" format but am getting string conversion Error Message

Comment: then you should swap formats like: `var fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(objFromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 2):

Your date `04/18/2017` is already in format `MM/dd/yyyy`. As the name `ParseExact` suggests, compiler tries to **Parse** your date in the same **Exact** format as provided by you. Hence the exception.

I guess you want

```
FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(objFromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                   .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Comment: am getting   this Error Message "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."